# ruby-on-rails: build associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are models Parent and Child. I can not understand how to make this logic:

1. If the table сhilds no record at the email which is then entered in the form of an entry in the table of parents, as well as in the table сhilds while in the status field record true.
2. If the table already has a record сhilds at the email which is entered in the form field and status = true, then do not create any new entries in the table or in the table parents сhilds
3. If the table already has a record сhilds at the email which is entered in the form field and status = false, it creates an entry in the table parents, as well as in the table сhilds while in the status field record true.

Still need to be able to create a new entry in the table сhilds through other forms of controller ChildsController
Writing in the table can only create сhilds current_user which field status = true. If an entry was created successfully in the status field write false

Thank you.

```
migrations parents
t.string "name"  

migrations childs
t.string "name" 
t.string "email"
t.integer "parent_id"
t.boolean  "status", default: false

model Parent
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :childs

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

model Child
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  validates :name, :email, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :parent
end

controller ParentsController
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @parent = Parent.new
    @parent.childs.build
  end

  def create
    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
    if @parent.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:name, childs_attributes: [:parent_id, :name, :email, :status])
  end

end


form1  to create entries in the tables of parents and childs
<%= form_for @parent do |parent_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= parent_form.text_field :name %>
    </div><br>
    <%= parent_form.fields_for :childs do |childs_form| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= childs_form.text_field :name %>
        </div><br>
        <div class="field">
          <%= childs_form.email_field :email %>
        </div><br>
    <% end %>
    <div class="action"><br>
      <%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
    </div>
<% end %>


form2 to create entries in the table childs
<%= form_for(@child) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div><br>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div><br>
<div class="action"><br>
  <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
</div>
<% end %>


controller ChildsController
class ChildsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @child = Child.new
  end

  def create
    @child = current_user.parent.childs.build(child_params)
    if @child.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private
  def child_params
    params.require(:child).permit(:name, :email)
  end

end
```

Comment: What does "shilds" mean?

Comment: Sorry, shilds should be childs

Comment: Can you make your questions more direct? I got very confused reading them :(

Comment: Divide the task into several subtasks. Start with the first. How do I create an entry in the table parents, if the table childs no record with a field of email = field from form and owner = true. If the record is created with it creates an entry in this field at childs owner assign true. If the parents table entry is not created, then do not create entries in the table childs